# Opening file-like object with Python wrapper of gdcm (Grassroots DICOM)

Tags: swig, dicom, gdcm

Using the [SWIG generated Python wrappers for gdcm](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page#Short_Presentation):

Is there some way to pass the `gdcm.ImageReader` a file-like object rather than having to pass the `fileName`?

Currently I load a DICOM file using:

```
    image_reader = gdcm.ImageReader()
    image_reader.SetFileName(fname)
```

but I see that the `image_reader` also has a method `SetFile` which takes a `gdcm::File` object.

There is also a `StreamImageReader` which has `SetStream(std::istream &inStream)`, but I do not know how to create a `inStream` acceptable object in Python.

Ideally I would be able to use the results from an `open` call or `StringIO` or `BytesIO`.

Answer (score 2):

No this is currently not possible. This is a current limitation of the automated SWIG wrapping of the GDCM C++ API.

Comment: Is there any update on this, i.e., is this now possible?